# Constructing a holomorphic function with a given zero set.

Tags: complex-analysis, weierstrass-factorization

So here are two questions:

Construct a holomorphic and bounded function on $\mathbb{D}$ with infinitely many zeros in $\mathbb{D}$ accumulating in $i$.

And construct and entire function with only zeros at $\{in^{\frac{1}{2}}\}, n \in \mathbb{N}$

For the first part I was going to go with Wierstrass Factorization theorem, but I believe the theorem only works if you do not have accumulation points. If so, may be something like a heavily modified $\tan(z)$ could work? I'm not sure, any help is appreciated.

The second part is this a good function? $f(z)=\prod^\infty_{n=0}(1-z/in^{\frac{1}{2}})$. Thanks!

Comment: Aaaargh, sorry, that's not what I meant to type, I have the edited version up.

Comment: Still diverges for obvious reasons. Did you look at wikipedia's article ?

Answer (score 1):

$\sin(z)$ is bounded on the strip $-\pi/2 < \text{Im}(z) < \pi/2$ and has zeros at $\pi n$ for integers $n$.  The strip can be mapped conformally to the right half plane $\mathbb H$ by $w = \exp(z)$, with $z = n \pi$ mapped to $w = \exp(n\pi)$ converging to $0$ as $n \to -\infty$, and then to the unit disk by
$\zeta = 2i/(1+w)-i$ with $\zeta \to i$ as $w \to 0$.  Inverting these maps,
$z = \text{Log}(w) = \text{Log}\left(\frac{i-\zeta}{i+\zeta}\right)$ where $\text{Log}$ is the principal branch of the logarithm, so your function in the first part can be 
$$ \sin \left(\text{Log}\left(\frac{i-\zeta}{i+\zeta}\right)\right) $$

For the second part, you want to use the Weierstrass Factorization Theorem.

Comment: Thank you so much! This actually works!, and by $\mathbb{H}$ you mean the upper half-plane $Im(z) >0$ is that right? Because I can see the Cayley and inverse Cayley transforms happening here.

Comment: No, I really mean the right half plane $\text{Re}(z) > 0$.